# Android Studio: Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, manifest

I recently trying to move the project to Android Studio. I exporting the APK due to this error

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 9 declared in library com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71

I have checked my manifest file but it was 9 instead of 8... What does that refering to... do I need to update anything... Note: I initially use eclipse and moving toward Android Studio.

Comment: have you check the build.gradle file? inside your app folder.

Comment: what is the target version?

Answer (score 2):

This may help.

modify your **minSdkVersion** to 9 in your build.gradle
or you can use **tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms"** in **uses-sdk** tag of your menifest.